# msal-browser login is stuck at callback url with code returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I installed msal-browser package and able to login but screen is stuck at call back url with code .

The samples given in the github repository returns access token in exchange of auth code.But the same code doesnt with my organizational code.

```
            const pc = new msal.PublicClientApplication(config);
            publicClient.loginRedirect(loginRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your redirect URL you added in code is not matching with the one you have configured. If you can provide more details about configuration we can help, but redirect url is possible cause or your login having some issues.